# Typescript and Puppeteer not allowing me to click an element from a `document.querySelectorAll`

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer

I am having a problem being able to call the `click` method on `selectedSelector`. I think this might be a types issue between what typescript's querySelectorAll return and what Puppeteer's querySelectorAll returns.

`await this.getSelectorFromArrayAndClick('.left-nav .open a', 'By Merchant');`

```js
 async getSelectorFromArrayAndClick(selectors: string, searchValue: string) {

    const selectedSelector: HTMLAnchorElement = await this.page.evaluate((selectors, searchValue) =>  {
      const queryList = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLAnchorElement>(selectors) as any;
      const listOfSelectors = Array.from(queryList) as any;
      const selector = listOfSelectors.find(e => e.text === searchValue) as any;
      return selector;

    }, selectors, searchValue);

    selectedSelector.click(); // does not exist
  }
```

I am unsure how I can get at the right type so I could call the click method on the selectedSelector.

Comment: Did you tried consoling `selector` before `return selector;`? `e.text`? I believe it should be `e.textContent`.

Comment: yeah it somehow becoming a object without the click method